# Why is v.clean not working?

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, topology, snapping, v.clean

I’m trying to clean the snapping errors from my line layer.
I have a problem with running the tool and the outputs.
During the run, many errors and warnings arise.
I tried to use the tool  in both UTM and WGS84 CRM , and also change the threshold and tolerance parameters.

Working on QGIS 3.18.3 version.

[image: the snap distance (0.028 meter)]

[image: this is the snap error (scale 1:2)]

**the log output:**

> QGIS version: 3.18.3-Zürich QGIS code revision: 735cc85be9 Qt version:
> 5.11.2 GDAL version: 3.1.4 GEOS version: 3.8.1-CAPI-1.13.3 PROJ version: Rel. 6.3.2, May 1st, 2020 Processing algorithm… Algorithm
> 'v.clean' starting… Input parameters: { '-b' : False, '-c' : False,
> 'GRASS_MIN_AREA_PARAMETER' : 0.0001, 'GRASS_OUTPUT_TYPE_PARAMETER' :
> 0, 'GRASS_REGION_PARAMETER' : None, 'GRASS_SNAP_TOLERANCE_PARAMETER' :
> 0.03, 'GRASS_VECTOR_DSCO' : '', 'GRASS_VECTOR_EXPORT_NOCAT' : False, 'GRASS_VECTOR_LCO' : '', 'error' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT', 'input' :
> 'Lines.shp', 'output' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT', 'threshold' : '0.03',
> 'tool' : [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASftP.png), 'type' : [0,1,2,3,4,5,6] }
>
> Attempting to use v.external for direct layer read g.proj -c
> wkt="C:/Users/Hanita/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_jRqlra/976ace9cd85e46a9aab846203bb108ac/crs.prj"
> v.external input="Lines.shp" output="vector_60ace3585a3222"
> --overwrite -o g.region n=39.798470915721985 s=39.79419787555197 e=-104.70319073330543 w=-104.71076847379005 v.clean
> input=vector_60ace3585a3222
> type="point,line,boundary,centroid,area,face,kernel" tool="snap"
> threshold="0.03" output=outputf19465d7dae74a13b455c5001ff252e0
> error=errorf19465d7dae74a13b455c5001ff252e0 --overwrite v.out.ogr
> type="auto" input="outputf19465d7dae74a13b455c5001ff252e0"
> output="C:\Users\Hanita\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_jRqlra\8494e58144e3435b9ae50f92146715ce\output.gpkg"
> format="GPKG" --overwrite v.out.ogr type="auto"
> input="errorf19465d7dae74a13b455c5001ff252e0"
> output="C:\Users\Hanita\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_jRqlra\d474e62fedac469ca82d7feddbe2b7b9\error.gpkg"
> format="GPKG" --overwrite Starting GRASS GIS... WARNING: Concurrent
> mapset locking is not supported on Windows Cleaning up temporary
> files... Executing
> <C:\Users\Hanita\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_jRqlra\grassdata\grass_batch_job.cmd>
> ... C:\Users\Hanita\Documents>chcp 65001 1>NUL
> C:\Users\Hanita\Documents>g.proj -c
> wkt="C:/Users/Hanita/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_jRqlra/976ace9cd85e46a9aab846203bb108ac/crs.prj"
> Default region was updated to the new projection, but if you have
> multiple mapsets `g.region -d` should be run in each to update the
> region from the default Projection information updated
> C:\Users\Hanita\Documents>v.external input="Lines.shp"
> output="vector_60ace3585a3222" --overwrite -o ERROR 1: Can't load
> requested DLL: C:\OSGEO4~1\bin\gdalplugins\ogr_MSSQLSpatial.dll 126:
> The specified module could not be found. ERROR 1: Can't load requested
> DLL: C:\OSGEO4~1\bin\gdalplugins\ogr_MSSQLSpatial.dll 126: The
> specified module could not be found. ERROR 1: Can't load requested
> DLL: C:\OSGEO4~1\bin\gdalplugins\ogr_MSSQLSpatial.dll 126: The
> specified module could not be found. ERROR 1: Can't load requested
> DLL: C:\OSGEO4~1\bin\gdalplugins\ogr_MSSQLSpatial.dll 126: The
> specified module could not be found. Over-riding projection check
> Building topology for vector map vector_60ace3585a3222@PERMANENT...
> Using external data format 'ESRI Shapefile' (feature type
> 'linestring') Registering primitives... 3 primitives registered 18
> vertices registered v.external complete. Link to vector map
> <vector_60ace3585a3222> created. C:\Users\Hanita\Documents>g.region
> n=39.798470915721985 s=39.79419787555197 e=-104.70319073330543
> w=-104.71076847379005 C:\Users\Hanita\Documents>v.clean
> input=vector_60ace3585a3222
> type="point,line,boundary,centroid,area,face,kernel" tool="snap"
> threshold="0.03" output=outputf19465d7dae74a13b455c5001ff252e0
> error=errorf19465d7dae74a13b455c5001ff252e0 --overwrite ERROR 1: Can't
> load requested DLL: C:\OSGEO4~1\bin\gdalplugins\ogr_MSSQLSpatial.dll
> 126: The specified module could not be found. ERROR 1: Can't load
> requested DLL: C:\OSGEO4~1\bin\gdalplugins\ogr_MSSQLSpatial.dll 126:
> The specified module could not be found. ERROR 1: Can't load requested
> DLL: C:\OSGEO4~1\bin\gdalplugins\ogr_MSSQLSpatial.dll 126: The
> specified module could not be found. ERROR 1: Can't load requested
> DLL: C:\OSGEO4~1\bin\gdalplugins\ogr_MSSQLSpatial.dll 126: The
> specified module could not be found. WARNING: Column 'id' : type int8
> (bigint) is stored as integer (4 bytes) some data may be damaged
> WARNING: Column 'id' : type int8 (bigint) is stored as integer (4
> bytes) some data may be damaged Note: In latitude-longitude coordinate
> system specify threshold in degree unit
> -------------------------------------------------- Tool: Threshold Snap vertices: 0.03
> -------------------------------------------------- Copying features...
> 33..66..100 WARNING: Unable to create index WARNING: Unable to copy table  for layer 1 from vector_60ace3585a3222@PERMANENT to
>  WARNING: Failed to copy
> attribute table to output vector map Rebuilding parts of topology...
> Building topology for vector map
> outputf19465d7dae74a13b455c5001ff252e0@PERMANENT... Registering
> primitives...
> -------------------------------------------------- Tool: Snap line to vertex in threshold Reading features... Snap vertices Pass 1: select
> points
> 0..33..66..100 Snap vertices Pass 2: assign anchor vertices
> 5..11..16..22..27..33..38..44..50..55..61..66..72..77..83..88..94..100 Snap vertices Pass 3: snap to assigned points
> 0..33..66..100
> -------------------------------------------------- Rebuilding topology for output vector map... Building topology for vector map
> outputf19465d7dae74a13b455c5001ff252e0@PERMANENT... Registering
> primitives...
> -------------------------------------------------- Building topology for error vector map... Building topology for vector map
> errorf19465d7dae74a13b455c5001ff252e0@PERMANENT... Registering
> primitives... C:\Users\Hanita\Documents>v.out.ogr type="auto"
> input="outputf19465d7dae74a13b455c5001ff252e0"
> output="C:\Users\Hanita\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_jRqlra\8494e58144e3435b9ae50f92146715ce\output.gpkg"
> format="GPKG" --overwrite ERROR 1: Can't load requested DLL:
> C:\OSGEO4~1\bin\gdalplugins\ogr_MSSQLSpatial.dll 126: The specified
> module could not be found. ERROR 1: Can't load requested DLL:
> C:\OSGEO4~1\bin\gdalplugins\ogr_MSSQLSpatial.dll 126: The specified
> module could not be found. WARNING: Unable to determine input map's
> vector feature type(s). ERROR: Key column <> not found
> C:\Users\Hanita\Documents>v.out.ogr type="auto"
> input="errorf19465d7dae74a13b455c5001ff252e0"
> output="C:\Users\Hanita\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_jRqlra\d474e62fedac469ca82d7feddbe2b7b9\error.gpkg"
> format="GPKG" --overwrite ERROR 1: Can't load requested DLL:
> C:\OSGEO4~1\bin\gdalplugins\ogr_MSSQLSpatial.dll 126: The specified
> module could not be found. ERROR 1: Can't load requested DLL:
> C:\OSGEO4~1\bin\gdalplugins\ogr_MSSQLSpatial.dll 126: The specified
> module could not be found. WARNING: No attribute table found -> using
> only category numbers as attributes Exporting 3 features...
> 33..66..100 v.out.ogr complete. 3 features (Line String type) written to  (GPKG format).
> C:\Users\Hanita\Documents>exit Execution of
> <C:\Users\Hanita\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_jRqlra\grassdata\grass_batch_job.cmd>
> finished. Cleaning up default sqlite database ... Cleaning up
> temporary files... Execution completed in 1.65 seconds Results:
> {'error':
> 'C:\Users\Hanita\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_jRqlra\d474e62fedac469ca82d7feddbe2b7b9\error.gpkg',
> 'output':
> 'C:\Users\Hanita\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_jRqlra\8494e58144e3435b9ae50f92146715ce\output.gpkg'}
>
> Loading resulting layers Algorithm 'v.clean' finished

Comment: Have you searched for the errors? If so, what did you find out?

Comment: ... ogr_MSSQLSpatial.dll seems to be missing, perhaps an incomplete installation?

Answer (score 3):

If I understand, your Lines.shp is in Longitude/Latitude WGS84, so units are degrees. The threshold you chose, 0.03, is about **3 kilometers**. The gap between the lines, that you showed in the screen shot, is less than 3 centimeters. So nothing to snap...

I suggest to **reproject** the Lines.shp to a new shapefile (or preferably geopackage) in UTM, then choose a snap threshold of 0.01 (= 1 cm)

Comment: Thank you so much! This solved my problem as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue just recently. I was leaving the output of the tool (by default) as a *temporary file* (i.e., a gpkg in the Temp folder on C drive). Just like yours above. What worked for me is that I specified the output **as a shapefile** and saved it **permanently**. Then, the tool worked.